# Map APIs to search for a street in a country

Tags: java, maps

I'm looking for an open Map API that I can search for a street name in a country, returning an array of possible locations. E.g.: my input is: eggmont street, england, and it returns a list where I may find Eggmont Street in england.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: How about https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library#usage_java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Google Maps Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library)

[Example usage](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library#usage_java):

```
// Replace the API key below with a valid API key.
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext().setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
GeocodingResult[] results =  GeocodingApi.geocode(context,
    "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043").await();
System.out.println(results[0].formattedAddress);
```

Comment: I've tried it in a sample project and that's the solution that I will adopt for my need. Thanks!